# Adding an Item to the top of a LongListSelector

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, data-binding, observablecollection

I have a Windows Phone app that follows the `Databound App` template. It's basically a `LongListSelector` control manipulated by an `ObservableCollection()` thing.

Adding things is easy: I just do this:

```
App.ViewModel.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { ThingOne = "Blah", ThingTwo = "BlahBlahBlah"});
```

But my Item gets added to the *bottom* of the LongListSelector. I'd like to add it to the *top*.

How do I do this? Can I specify this behavior within the `Items.Add()` statement? Or is it something to do with the `MainViewModel`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
App.ViewModel.Items.Insert(0, new ItemViewModel() { ThingOne = "Blah", ThingTwo = "BlahBlahBlah"});
```

Comment: I couldn't have hoped for a simpler solution - and it works! Thank you! @Bolu

Answer (score 1):

> Can I specify this behavior within the Items.Add() statement?

User `Insert` instead :[Collection.Insert Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132411%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)